# Efficient method to find unique values in 2D std::vector<vector<double>>

Tags: c++, vector, stl, unique

Given a 1D vector `std::vector<double> v`, the most efficient way to identify unique elements that I know is:

```
sort(v.begin(), v.end());
v.erase(unique(v.begin(), v.end()), v.end());
```

**What is the most efficient way to find the unique elements in 2D vector (i.e. the unique elements among all the elements of 2D matrix)** `std::vector<std::vector<double>> v`

EDIT: One obvious solution could be to flatten the 2D matrix and apply the above method, but is there any more efficient way?

Comment: I would iterate exactly once, storing the results in a map. Key is the double element, value is how many times it appears. Then iterate the map, grabbing elements with a value greater than one.

Comment: You should also consider using hashing, it preserves row ordering and could be faster (amortized O(m*n) if alteration of the original is permitted, O(2*m*n) if a copy is required) than sort/unique -- especially noticeable for large matrices (on small matrices you are probably better off with Billy's solution since his requires no additional memory allocation to keep track of the hashes.)http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3169960/determining-the-unique-rows-of-a-2d-array-vectorvectort

Answer (score 0):

Take that code snippet you have, and apply it to each vector in the outer vector.

```
for (int i = 0; i < outerVector.size(); ++i) {
  // Your snippet
}
```

If you have to touch each element in a 2d array, then the best you can hope for is an `O(n²)` algorithm.

Comment: This method would find unique elements in each vector, but I need the unique elements among all elements of 2D matrix

Comment: I see -- you'd have to keep track of your unique values somehow. Of course, if you could somehow maintain a flattened 2d vector, you could just stick with your original snippet :p

Comment: yes, this is true, but flattening this vector is not cheap extra operation

Comment: Flattening the vector is cheap (order N) compared with sorting it (order N log N).