# Find the unique rows in Binary 2D array

Tags: c++, arrays, matrix, multidimensional-array

Print the row numbers which are unique.

The following is my implementation:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cmath>

int rowsToInt(int m[][5], int row, int cloumLen) {
    int sum = 0;
    // m[row][column]
    for (int i = 0; i < cloumLen; i++) {
        sum += m[row][i]*(std::pow(2,i));
    }
    return sum;
}

void removeDuplicate(int m[][5], int row, int column) {
    if (!m) {
        return;
    }

    int tracker = 0;
    int mask = 1;   
    int value;

    for (int i = 0; i < row; i++) {
        value = rowsToInt(m, i, column); // 3
        if (((mask << (value - 1)) & tracker) == 0) {
            // print unique row
            std::cout << "row: " << i << " is unique" << std::endl;

            // set that bit to 1
            tracker = tracker ^ (mask << (value - 1));
        }
    }
}

int main() {
    int array[5][5] = {
        {0,1,0,0,1},
        {1,0,1,1,0},
        {0,1,0,0,1},
        {1,1,1,0,0},
        {1,1,0,1,1}
    };
    removeDuplicate(array, 5, 5);
    return 0;
}
```

output is:

```
row: 0 is unique
row: 1 is unique
row: 3 is unique
row: 4 is unique
```

what is the run time? I think its O(row*column); because each row then each column element are visited.

Is this the most optimal run time?

Comment: For a "binary array", you are wasting a lot of space by using a 2D array of `int`.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3169960/determining-the-unique-rows-of-a-2d-array-vectorvectort This link should help you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The slowest part in your code is `std::pow()`, for array with 200000 rows it'll be called one million times that takes considerable time, so don't use it in loops without necessary. If you need powers of 2, the fastest way is using bitwise rotation, as did @chqrlie. In general, if you need powers on N, you can get them as follow:

```
int rowsToInt (bool m[][5], int row, int cloumLen) {
    int sum = 0;
    for (int i = 0, p = 1; i < cloumLen; i++) {
        sum += m[row][i]*p;
        p *= N;
    }
    return sum;    
}
```

Now for optimization. If you're working with binary matrix, why are you using integer one? It takes 4 times more RAM, so use `bool array[rows][cols]`. Number of rows and cols are constants, so there's no need to pass them to functions. You can just declare global `const int rows = 7, cols = 5`. And one more important factor. If you are searching for unique binary rows in big matrix, it's worth to count found ones. If you've already found 2^cols of them, just leave the loop.

Your search method is rather complicated. Let me show two easier ways to solve your problem.

More compact way:

```
// the code inside removeDuplicate function
unsigned long tracker = 0; // now it looks like 32 zeros
for (int i = 0; i < row; ++i) {
    int value = rowsToInt (m, i, column); // getting dec value

    if (((tracker >> value) & 1) == 0) { // if the valueth bit is equal to zero
        tracker |= (1UL << value); // set it equal to one
        std::cout << "row: " << i << " is unique" << std::endl;
        if (tracker = 0xffffffff) return; // if all bits are equal to 1, we've found all the unique rows
    }
}
```

And one of the simplest:

```
// the code inside removeDuplicate function
bool found[32] = {false}; // using array instead of UL
int counter = 0; // and simple counter of unique rows

for (int i = 0; i < row; i++) {
    int value = rowsToInt (m, i, column); // getting dec value

    if (!found[value]) { // if the valueth element is equal to zero
        found[value] = true; // set it equal to one
        ++counter; // and increase the counter
        std::cout << "row: " << i << " is unique" << std::endl;
        if (counter == 32) return;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Your method seems to have a problem:

- function `rowsToInt` converts the subarray of 5 `int` to a value between `0` and `31` assuming these values are strictly binary (0 or 1).
- in function `removeDuplicates`, you use these values as shift counters in the expression: `(mask << (value-1))` where `mask` is an `int` with value `1`. It is an astute way to keep track of rows seen so far, but the expression invokes undefined behavior for `value == 0`.

You should fix this problem using `unsigned long` type for `tracker`, guaranteed to have at least 32 bits, and `(1UL << value)` defined and different for values `0` to `31`.

The complexity is indeed **O(rows * cols)**, but the algorithm is inherently limited to `cols <= 5`, so it is difficult to talk about complexity when `cols` cannot grow arbitrarily.

Furthermore, using `pow(2, i)` is very inefficient to compute binary values.

Here is a simpler version:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cmath>

int rowsToInt(int m[][5], int row, int cloumLen) {
    int sum = 0;
    // m[row][column]
    for (int i = 0; i < cloumLen; i++) {
        sum += m[row][i] << i;
    }
    return sum;
}

void removeDuplicate(int m[][5], int row, int column) {
    if (!m) {
        return;
    }

    unsigned long tracker = 0;

    for (int i = 0; i < row; i++) {
        int value = rowsToInt(m, i, column); // 3
        if (((1UL << value) & tracker) == 0) {
            // print unique row
            std::cout << "row: " << i << " is unique" << std::endl;
             // set that bit to 1
            tracker |= 1UL << value;        
        }   
    }
}

int main() {
    int array[7][5] = {
        {0,1,0,0,1},
        {1,0,1,1,0},
        {0,1,0,0,1},
        {1,1,1,0,0},
        {1,1,0,1,1},
        {0,0,0,0,0},
        {0,0,0,0,0},
    };
    removeDuplicate(array, 7, 5);
    return 0;
}
```